# Regex capturing groups in java

Tags: java, regex

I am attempting to create a regular expression which must capture 4 groups from 4 provided decimals given the users input string.

```
input = "1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4"
```

My current expression :

```
[-+]?([0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)
```

My question is, how would I achieve `matcher.group(1) = 1.1 , matcher.group(2) = 2.2` , `matcher.group(3) = 3.3` ,`matcher.group(4) = 4.4` for use in main program??

I understand that my expression is only capturing 1 group containing all four doubles, but in order to use them they must be separate groups.

Comment: "but in order to use them they must be separate groups." or use `find()` until there will be nothing to found and handle what you got in group 1 (or 0 if you want entire match - including `+` and `-`).

Comment: wouldn't a `.split("\s")` give the same result?

Comment: How would I handle group 0 to be used as four variables?

Comment: `String [] groups = input.split("\s");` Then you use it as `groups[0]` or `groups[1]` or `groups[2]` ....

Comment: The above expression only captures the last double in the string

Comment: @JorgeCampos I would recommend that too, but you have to be careful, it is `input.split("\\s")`.

Comment: Expression will capture ".99" as well

Comment: Cant you use just `Scanner` and `nextFloat` ??

Comment: The assignment in question requires me to use pattern/matcher to capture 4 doubles in separate groups to be used individually, so I sadly cannot use scanner due to the input coming from a JOption input.

Comment: **cannot use scanner due to the input coming from a JOption input** u still can.

Comment: `([-+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[-+]?[0-9]+) +([-+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[-+]?[0-9]+) +([-+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[-+]?[0-9]+) +([-+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[-+]?[0-9]+)` not very elegant but does the job. https://regex101.com/r/NyYSFM/1

Comment: Sir maraca thank you!

Comment: @maraca yes, of course... you are right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
"(\\d+\\.\\d+) (\\d+\\.\\d+) (\\d+\\.\\d+) (\\d+\\.\\d+)"
```